# Saber si una variable esta en un arreglo - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

necesito saber si una variable @hs_start que contiene una hora 'x', coincide con algún valor del campo hs_turn de mi tabla Turn. Lo que realice en mi controlador de Turn fue un select con una condicion where donde traigo todos los datos de mi tabla Turn de la siguiente manera:

> @turnos_ocupados = Turn.where("provider_id='#{@prov}' AND date_turn='#{@fecha}' ")

Ahora lo que deseo es en mi view index de turn es traer ese arreglo @turnos_ocupados para saber si algun valor del campo 'hs_turn' coincide con la variable @hs_start y asi realizar determinada accion. La menera que estoy intentado hacer esto en mi view es la siguiente:

> if @turnos_ocupados.include?("@hs_start")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iba a poner esto en un comentario, pero creo que quedará mejor en una respuesta para explicarlo mejor, a pesar de que no responda específicamente tu pregunta. Dos detalles:

- En vez de `map`, podrías considerar usar [`pluck`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) que es mas óptimo en términos de consultar a la BD solo por los atributos que requieres.
- Muy importante, no se de donde viene esas variables `@prov` y `@fecha`, pero pasándole a tu `where` como parámetro `"provider_id='#{@prov}' AND date_turn='#{@fecha}' "`,estás haciendo tu app. susceptible a un ataque de [SQL Injection](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/sql-injection-ruby-on-rails-development/), al usar interpolación en un string. Hay varias formas de evitar eso:

```
# La más fácil y simple. En caso que solo hayan AND en tu consulta, puedes
# pasarlas como un hash.
Turn.where(provider_id: @prov, date_turn: @fecha)
# La otra forma es con ? y pasando c/u de las variables que reemplazarán a
# dichos ?
Turn.where('provider_id = ? AND date_turn = ?', @prov, @fecha)
# Usando :nombre y pasando un hash con los nombres. Este puede serte util cuando
# una variable tienes que agregarla en más de una parte de tu consulta.
Turn.where('provider_id = :prov AND date_turn = :fecha', prov: @prov, fecha: @fecha)
```

Cada una de estas formas hace una sanitización de los parámetros que provees, lo que no hace la forma que estás usando actualmente.

Comment: +1 a la prevención de _SQL injection_.

Comment: Muchas gracias !! Voy a intentarlo modificar de la manera en que lo explicas. Te agradezco mucho la respuesta.

Comment: Lo que no me ha funcionado es el pluck. Lo realice de esta manera y nada: "@turnos_ocupados = Turn.where('provider_id = ? AND date_turn = ?', @prov, @fecha).pluck(&:hs_turn)"

Comment: Puede ser que no lleve el signo ampersand (&) dentro del pluck?

Comment: @francofernandez efectivamente. `pluck` recibe un symbol como parámetro, no un block

Answer (score 1):

Bueno esto ya es cabala la de publicar y que luego encuentre la manera de resolverlo jaja
Lo resolví realizando lo siguiente en mi controlador:

> @turnos_ocupados = Turn.where("provider_id='#{@prov}' AND date_turn='#{@fecha}' ").map(&:hs_turn)

En mi vista no cambio mucho, solo le saque las comillas dobles que tenia a la ariable:

> if @turnos_ocupados.include?(@hs_start)

Comment: Suele pasar eso de publicar y encontrar solo la respuesta :)